# React state change not triggering useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with the following

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
     {isOpen && (
                <Drop
                  overflow="unset"
                  align={{ right: "left", top: "bottom", bottom: "bottom" }}
                  style={{ overflowY: "scroll" }}
                  target={targetRef.current}
                  onClickOutside={() => setIsOpen(false)}
                  onEsc={() => setIsOpen(false)}
                >
                  <Calendar
                    date={
                      value
                        ? moment(value)
                            .format()
                            .split("T")[0]
                        : null
                    }
                    onSelect={evt => {
                      onCalendarSelect(evt.toString());
                    }}
                    size="small"
                    {...(calendarPassedProps as CalendarProps)}
                  />
                </Drop>
              )}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("useEffect ",isOpen)
}, [isOpen])
```

Where onCalendarSelect is

```
const onCalendarSelect = (v: string) => {
  console.log(isOpen) //always showing true
  setIsOpen(false)
  const date = moment(v)
    .format()
    .split("T")[0]
    .replaceAll("-", "/");
  try {
    setValue(date);
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(date);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Prevent invalid dates
  }
};
```

Now, when I click outside of the drop , and onCLickOutside is triggered, my isOpen useEffect is triggered, hence closing the calendar.

But whenever I trigger the function OnCalendarSelect which does `setIsOpen(false)` , nothing changes and the useeffect is not being triggered.

What can the issue be?

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mre]. It's not clear how you are passing `setIsOpen` to `onCalendarSelect` etc. You probably have a mistake somewhere in the code you have not shown.

Comment: Perhaps the `setValue` or the `onChange` cause the `isOpen` to be set again to `true`. We cannot really help without a working example that shows the issue.

Comment: invalid JSX render

Comment: can you add `onChange` code as well?

Comment: As far as we can see from your code, you always call `setIsOpen(false)`. Not only, but `isOpen` initial value is `false` so its totally normal that `useEffect` will be never triggered (because useEffect will work when you change state's value). Could you show us where `isOpen` is set to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

1.You are not providing a complete component example so we know if there are conflicts, if there's a different setIsOpen that overwrites the one in this component or any other bugs that might be caused by your logic.
2.You are not specifying the relationship of onCalendarSelect and this component. Are you passing the function as a prop? Are you extracting it from context? Is it defined inside the component?
3. Do you have another setIsOpen in the app that could overwrite the one here?

However. I think you should pass the setIsOpen function to your onCalendarSelect function. As in the example below. If this does not work please provide the full component code and the code of the component where onCalendarSelect is.

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
     {isOpen && (
                <Drop
                  overflow="unset"
                  align={{ right: "left", top: "bottom", bottom: "bottom" }}
                  style={{ overflowY: "scroll" }}
                  target={targetRef.current}
                  onClickOutside={() => setIsOpen(false)}
                  onEsc={() => setIsOpen(false)}
                >
                  <Calendar
                    date={
                      value
                        ? moment(value)
                            .format()
                            .split("T")[0]
                        : null
                    }
                    onSelect={evt => {
                      onCalendarSelect(evt.toString(), setIsOpen);
                    }}
                    size="small"
                    {...(calendarPassedProps as CalendarProps)}
                  />
                </Drop>
              )}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("useEffect ",isOpen)
}, [isOpen])


const onCalendarSelect = (v: string, setIsOpen: any) => {
  console.log(isOpen) //always showing true
  setIsOpen(false)
  const date = moment(v)
    .format()
    .split("T")[0]
    .replaceAll("-", "/");
  try {
    setValue(date);
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(date);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Prevent invalid dates
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding a evt.stopPropagation

```
<Drop
              overflow="unset"
              align={{ right: "left", top: "bottom", bottom: "bottom" }}
              style={{ overflowY: "scroll" }}
              target={targetRef.current}
              onClickOutside={() => setIsOpen(false)}
              onClick={(evt: React.MouseEvent) => {
                evt.stopPropagation();
              }}
            >
```